# How to delete folders except two with linux

Tags: linux

I have many directories of backup starting with "backup_".

I want to keep only the two last created folders.

I did this command to show the last two created:

```
ls -1 -t -d */ | head -2
```

The problem is i don't know how to exclude the result of that command from remove command (rm -rf | ...).

I know grep -v only works with strings.

Comment: If you're truly happy parsing `ls` to generate the list (you really shouldn't be!), you could do `ls -t -d * | sed -e 1,2d | xargs rm`

Comment: Is there a timestamp in the directory names?

Comment: i found this commnad to be working "ls -t -d * | sed -e 1,2d | xargs rm" is there something i should modify further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `xargs` is the tool you want to use to pass a generated list of names as arguments to a command.  In your case, you just need to invert the `head -2` to a command that prints everything except the first 2 lines.  eg:

```
cmd-to-generate-file-list | sed -e 1,2d | xargs rm
```

The `sed` will delete the first two lines, and `xargs` will call `rm` with each line of output as an argument.  Note that it is not generally safe to use `ls` to generate the file list, but that is a different issue entirely.

Comment: is this command correct "ls -t | sed '1,2d' | xargs rm -rf" ?

Comment: If `ls` is indeed generating the list you want, with each name on a single line and non names containing whitespace or `-` (eg, if the names are "reasonable"), that should work.

Comment: this is my final command "ls -t -d */ |  grep "^backup_" | sed '1,2d' | xargs rm -rf"

Comment: `grep | sed` is an anti-pattern.  Do the pattern match with the glob: `ls -td "backup_*/" | ...`

Answer (score 1):

A `zsh` specific approach:

```sh
setopt extended_glob # Turn on extended globbing if it's not already enabled
dirs=( backup_*(#q/om) ) # Match only directories, sorted by modification time - newest first
rm -rf "${dirs[@]:2}" # Delete all but the first two elements of that array of directory names
```

---

See [the documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) for more on `zsh` glob qualifiers like the above uses. They can make things with filenames that are tedious or difficult to do in other shell dialects trivial.