# Recursivley go to directories that start with *TEST* and preserve only the latest 5 folders

Tags: linux, shell

Here is my directory structure.

```
./TEST1/automation
./TEST2_1/automation
./TEST3.4/automation
./general/automation
```

I want to preserve only the latest 5 sub-folders under all directories that starts with `TEST*/automation`.

Currently, my script goes into each directory as below and executes the command:

```
./TEST1/automation
ls -dt */ | tail -n +5 | xargs rm -rf
./TEST2_1/automation
ls -dt */ | tail -n +5 | xargs rm -rf
./TEST3.4/automation
ls -dt */ | tail -n +5 | xargs rm -rf
```

Everytime we add a new folder that starts with TEST, I've to manually update the script.

Basically, go into all directories that starts with `TEST*/automation` and preseve only latest 5 folders.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your script _executes the command ./TEST1/automation_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete folders except two with linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400332/how-to-delete-folders-except-two-with-linux)

Comment: I want to go into each directory that start with TEST*/automation and preserve only the lastet 5 folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
find -regex '.*/TEST.*/automation' -print0 |xargs -0 -I {} -n1 bash -c 'cd "{}"; ls -rt |  tail -n +4 | xargs -I {} echo rm -rf -- "{}"'
```

If the output looks alright (check that it does indeed show "rm ... " for all files/directories you want to get rid of) remove the `echo`.

Caveat:  the second part of execution (the first `xargs` does **not** explicitly look for directories, it will also list files. From your description it's unclear whether your `automation` directories contain both files and directories or just directories.

Comment: Yes, it contains files and folders.